# Within same Activity one fragment will portrait and another one is landscape

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on fragments,In one activity i have two fragments , need to show one fragment in portrait mode and if swipes to another fragment it comes in landscape mode.but i am able to show both fragments in either portrait or landscape , is it possible in fragments to show like this ????
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Oh yes? What have you tried? Codes maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you set that the second fragment layout is

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

in the 2FragmentLayout.XML, it should works.

Comment: but this orientation is for activity , i want within same activity one fragment is in vertical and one more is in landscape

Comment: You have to set this information on the fragment layout, not in the activity one.